# How to look up the type of a method returning a type parameter with scala reflection?

Tags: scala

```
trait F[S]{
  def evaluate(): S
}
```

From typeOf[F[Double]] how can find that the return type of "evaluate" is Double?

```
typeOf[F[Double]]
 .decls
 .filter(_.name.toString=="evaluate")
 .head
 .asMethod
 .returnType
 .dealias
```

==> S

The type information that evaluate returns a double hasn't been erased -- it just seems like its hard to look up and match up with the type parameters:

```
typeOf[F[Double]].typeArgs
```

==> List(Double)

Its possible that my classes may have many type parameters, so I can't be sure that S is the first type parameter, but the types of the type parameters seem to be known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `asSeenFrom`.

```
val tpe = typeOf[F[Double]]

tpe.decls
  .filter(_.name.toString == "evaluate")
  .head
  .asMethod
  .returnType
  .asSeenFrom(tpe, tpe.typeSymbol)
```